# String.length and concatenated strings

Tags: f#

The two expressions below produce the same output:

```
> ("hello" + " " + "world!");;
val it : string = "hello world!"

> "hello" + " " + "world!";;
val it : string = "hello world!"
```

Why then [`String.length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370387.aspx) works with the first but not with the second one?

```
> String.length ("hello" + " " + "world!");;
val it : int = 12

> String.length "hello" + " " + "world!";;

  String.length "hello" + " " + "world!";;
  ------------------------^^^

stdin(57,25): error FS0001: The type 'string' does not match the type 'int'
```

This was generated on FSI 14.0.22214.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parentheses are overriding the normal operator precedence. In particular function & argument has a very high precedence, so in the latter case it is being evaluated as

```
(String.length "hello") + " " + "world!"
```

and then trying to add a number to a string.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because functions bind more strongly than the (+) operator.

```
> String.length "hello" + " " + "world!"
```

Evaluates to:

```
> 5 + " " + "world!"
```

Which produces the same error:

```
> 5 + " " + "world!";;

  5 + " " + "world!";;
  ----^^^

stdin(1,5): error FS0001: The type 'string' does not match the type 'int'
```